# How to restrict invoice number to exactly 10 characters through form personalization in oracle apps

Tags: oracle-apps

My requirement is when the draft invoice is approved release button is enabled in release block we can enter invoice number. I need to restrict the invoice number exactly equal to 10 digits. If the user enters invoice number less than or greater than 10 I need to show error. Every thing is working fine but the problem is suppose for example if user enters invoice number less than 10 characters and presses *ok* error is shown and if user clicks *cancel* button after that. The release block is closed and the invoice status is changed to released and invoice number will be the number which is given by user, but my requirement is suppose user clicks *cancel* after pressing *ok* button the invoice status should not change to *released*.

I am using when-validate-record trigger for release block and in condition checking whether length of invoice_number is 10 and based on that showing error.

Comment: Try formatting your question in a reasonable way. Question may be better on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: What's your source code currently look like? It's easier to understand source...